# Why is this O(N^3) and not O(N^4)?

Tags: java, big-o

```
public static int g(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    int t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int tgt = list.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j) == tgt) 
                t += list.get(j);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Shouldn't the if statement make the complexity O(N^4)?

Comment: I recommend to not have ˋLinkedListˋ as type of argument, rather use ˋListˋ. In this way you can also use an ˋArrayListˋ and the runtime is lower. For this problem it would also reduce complexity if you put the initial list to an ˋArrayListˋ

Comment: You can do the same with O(N^2) complexity by using iterators:
for (int tgt :list) {  //O(N) loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if statements has nothing to do with the time complexity - the operation of an if-statement has time complexity `O(1)`, but the work in an if-statement can have a greater time complexity.

It's because `list.get(i)` is of `O(n)`. To get the n:th element of a LinkedList you need to step n times in the list to find it. This is because a LinkedList doesn't save its indexes, only the first and last element in the list, and then its direct neighbours.

This is the time complexity for each of your functions:

```
public static int g(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
    int t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {           // O(n) - loop
        int tgt = list.get(i);                        // O(n)

        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {   // O(n) - loop
            if (list.get(j) == tgt)                   // O(n)
                t += list.get(j);                     // O(n)
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Since you're only iterating over 2 loops, it will initially make the time complexity `O(n^2)`. The 3 calls of `list.get(i)` will make each make a time complexity of `O(n)`, thus resulting in `3*O(n)`. This is however defaulted to `O(n)`, and making the final time complexity to `O(n) * O(n) * 3*O(n) => O(n^3)`

#### Extra

**On an unrelated note**: You see that when you call `list.get(j)` twice, in the innermost loop, you will cause the program to iterate over the list twice, even though you just got the value.

```
if (list.get(j) == tgt)
    t += list.get(j);
```

Chances are that the processor or compiler will optimize this and save the value in the cache, but it's still a good idea to call `list.get(j)` once and store its value.

Answer (score 2):

If statements are not loops.

Each get may take O(n), but the statements in its body are executed after the condition. So the if statement takes O(n)+O(n) (for the two gets), which is O(n).

That is nested inside two nested loops over a list of size n, so overall it is O(n^3).